# I want to replace the string with the first occurence in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am cleaning the data for modeling and I want to replace the multiple words in a string with the first word in a list.

Can anyone help with the Python code to solve this problem?

Data:

```
id  String
1   a;b
2   b;e
3   c;d
4   a;f
5   a;c;h
6   b;c;d
7   e;c
8   f;a;c
9   h;e;c
10  b;a;d
```

List:

```
b
c
f
h
e
d
a
```

Output:

```
id  Result
1   b
2   b
3   c
4   f
5   c
6   b
7   c
8   c
9   c
10  b
```

Comment: Your description does not match your sample output.  Why 1 b and not 1 a, for example?

Comment: Is the data in a pandas dataframe?  Are you wanting the first word separated by the ; delimiter, or the first letter?

Comment: The data is in pandas dataframe. I want to replace the string a;b with the first occurence in a list. for example, b comes before a  in a list so the string a;b should be replaced with b.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect that. You should give all relevant information of your problem. The types of inputs is pretty relevant I would say...

Comment: is there also a guaranteed match between input and reference list? please also clarify on that.

Comment: @MrFuppes There is no guaranteed match between input and reference list. I want the function to return the original/same string if there is no match in the reference list.

Comment: @MrFuppes For example   id  String
1   a;b
2   b;e;n If n is not present in reference list the function should return string b;e;n

Comment: @Amy then I suggest to modify the function in brb 's answer with an `else: return x`

Comment: @MrFuppes I tried executing your code but its throwing error for the values that are not in reference list.

Comment: @Amy, sorry, made an edit to correct. If you work with `pandas`, I'd suggest you use the `pandas` method anyway, since it can be applied directly to a `df`.

Comment: @MrFuppes Its working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Amy, I hope that my answer at least helps/shows what you *could* do (if not using `pandas`. I've added some comments to the code to show another, maybe a bit more elegant solution using `enumerate`.

Comment: @Amy, can you clarify comment "For example id String 1 a;b 2 b;e;n If n is not present in reference list the function should return string b;e;n" ; so all elements need to be in the reference list?  Ie since b is in the reference list would you want it to return b or return b;e;n because n is missing?  I can modify function below depending on whether you want (a) if any element is missing return string; or (b) if all elements are missing return string.

Comment: @brb Thanks for your help. I used if all instead of if any to address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Modified to apply to a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : range(1,11),
    'String' :('a;b','b;e','c;d','a;f','a;c;h','b;c;d','e;c','f;a;c','h;e;c','b;a;d'),
})

someList = ['b','c','f','h','e','d','a']

def firstOccurance(x):
    for l in someList:
        if l in x:
            return l
            break

df['String'] = df['String'].apply(firstOccurance)
```

Comment: I will modify to reflect that you have a dataframe to begin with

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for your help.